# Understanding the parameter structure in jquery's one() method

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand jQuery's `one()` method at [jqapi.com](http://jqapi.com/#p=one) but I having a hard time understanding how to read and interpret the syntax of parameter as shown below, especially the `events [,data]` part.

```
one(events [, data] , handler(eventObject)) → jQuery
```

Please help me understand the above.

Comment: events="click","mouseenter" etc. Data: If you want to pass data to your event (you likely do not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [api page](http://jqapi.com/#p=one):

`events` - **String** - A string containing one or more JavaScript event types, such as "click" or "submit," or custom event names.

`data` - **PlainObject** - An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler.

`handler(eventObject)` - **Function** - A function to execute at the time the event is triggered.

Parameters in [ ] are optional, so you can do

`.one('click', someFn)` or `.one('click', {someData:'data'}, someFn)`

Comment: the confusing part is `[, data]`. As you show the optional, `{someData:'data'}` is the second parameter so the comma should come before as `,[data]` in `events, [data] , handler(eventObject)`. Putting the comma after `[,` in `events [, data] , handler(eventObject)` makes the `events[,data]` read as array not string.

Comment: It means that [....] is optional but IF it is there, you need a comma in front of it. It is not an array

Comment: The [ ] is not array syntax in this case - it's denoting that the parameter is optional. If you're including it, you don't need to put the [ ]

Comment: Thanks, that's why SO is awesome, gets you answers for stupid question. thank myself for asking this question (initially wasn't going to).  Missing link in reading docs, will greatly speed up learning.